# How to open multiple TXT files under for loop and assigning a names to each file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the `td` at first which contains the name of different jobs(with links). And I want to save the data which I'll again scrape from those 'td' links (data of those respective jobs from their web page) in different txt files. I want the scraped data to be separately saved of each web pages in different txt files. Can I do so? Please share your idea if you know anything regarding it!!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main = "https://deltaimmigration.com.au/Australia-jobs/"

def First():
    r = requests.get(main)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    links = []
    with open("links.txt", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        for item in soup.findAll("td", {'width': '250'}):
            item = item.contents[1].get("href")[3:]
            item = f"https://deltaimmigration.com.au/{item}"
            f.write(item+"\n")
            links.append(item)
    print(f"We Have Collected {len(links)} urls")
    return links

def Second():
    links = First() 
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for link in links:
            print(f"Extracting {link}")
            r = req.get(link,timeout = 100)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
            for item in soup.findAll("table", {'width': '900'}):
                return item

def Third():
    r = requests.get(main)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    result = Second()
    for item in soup.findAll("td", {'width': '250'}):
        with open(item.text + '.txt', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            f.write('result')           

Third()
```

I tried with the following:

```py
with open(item.text + '.txt', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
```

but I'm getting error as

```
File "e:/test/check.py", line 10, in Third with open(item.text + '.txt', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' Vegetable Grower (Aus)/market Gardener (NZ).txt'"
```

Comment: Well, obviously you need to download the data from the links, so you need to do `requests.get` for every one of them, inside your loop.  Also, `'{item}.txt'` will not work - if your Python is at least 3.6, `f'{item}.txt'` will work, othewise use `item + '.txt'`…

Comment: @Błotosmętek Actually it's item.text

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx which precisely means "will not work **as intended**", since the same filename will be used every time, destroying previous contents of the file.

Comment: @Błotosmętek No, I mean `item.text + '.txt'` cause `item` is an `object`, not `str`

Comment: edit your question and include more details to be able to understand your question.

Comment: I tried " with open(item.text + '.txt', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:" but I'm getting error as  "File "e:/test/check.py", line 10, in Third
    with open(item.text + '.txt', 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' Vegetable Grower (Aus)/market Gardener (NZ).txt'"

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel comment section is just for answering volunteers questions ! kindly edit your question with those details.

Comment: Okay...Thank you so much...I just had edited the question above...!!

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel you welcome, check the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main = "https://deltaimmigration.com.au/Australia-jobs/"


def First():
    r = requests.get(main)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
    links = []
    names = []
    with open("links.txt", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
        for item in soup.findAll("td", {'width': '250'}):
            name = item.contents[1].text
            item = item.contents[1].get("href")[3:]
            item = f"https://deltaimmigration.com.au/{item}"
            f.write(item+"\n")
            links.append(item)
            names.append(name)
    print(f"We Have Collected {len(links)} urls")
    return links, names


def Second():
    links, names = First()
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for link, name in zip(links, names):
            print(f"Extracting {link}")
            r = req.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html5lib')
            for item in soup.findAll("table", {'width': '900'}):
                with open(f"{name}.txt", 'w', newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
                    f.write(item.text)


Second()
```

Comment: I tried your answer where I also assigned the timeout to 100 but tho I'm facing the error like "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))".....Do you have idea why??

Comment: I’ve replied to the same question yesterday on your other post but looks like you just ignoring and asking again.

Comment: No, I tried assigning both timeout & proxy....but I'm getting same error after scraping few links!!

Comment: @BidhyaPokharel I've tested the code for a while. looks like the issue is in your end. https://pasteboard.co/IXniyX3.png